# Batch file - Redirect both the command and the output to a file

Tags: batch-file

I am able to use [redirection](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) operator to redirect the output of command line commands to a file.

```
dir >> sample.txt 2>&1
```

But just the output gets redirected. I would also like to write the command executed to the file (dir in the above example), so that the log file would show the command executed and the output of it.

One method I can think of is to store the command in a string, redirect the string to the file and then execute the string so that the output gets redirected. Is there a simpler way to do this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `ECHO ON`.

```
@echo off
call :commandAndOutput > out.txt
exit /b

:commandAndOutput
echo on
cd
dir
@echo off
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own command. For example you create a `ddir.bat` like this :

```
@echo off&cls
echo %cd%^> dir %*
dir %*
```

and then in place of calling `dir` you call your new command

```
ddir *.* /b > output.txt
```

That will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is double up your command.  First ECHO into >> your file, then same thing without the echo.  For instance.

```
ECHO "DISM /get-mountedwiminfo" >> B:\Sample.txt
DISM /get-mountedwiminfo >> B:\Sample.txt
```

Result in text file.

```
DISM /get-mountedwiminfo

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385

Mounted images:


No mounted images found.

The operation completed successfully.
```